# barbuttonitem now showing up, presentmodalviewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a need to show PDF files modally, when my user clicks on some buttons I load the PDF into a class and present it modally, now I need to provide the user with ab utton on the modalVC to close or go back so I added RightBarButtonItem, the prioblem is that its not showing up? This is code the load 
the PDF

```
     [self.pdfViewController.view addSubview:pdfViewer];
     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]      
     initWithRootViewController:pdfViewController];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(shutDown)];
     [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the bar button to the wrong viewController. It should belong to the viewController inside your presented navigationController. This is pdfViewController.

Additionally...

- assuming `self.pdfViewController` is the same object as `pdfViewController`, it's best if you refer to it consistently
- `presentModalViewController` is deprecated since at least ios5.0, you should be using `presentViewController:animated:completion`

So your code should look something like this

```
 [self.pdfViewController.view addSubview:pdfViewer];
 UINavigationController *navController = 
   [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.pdfViewController];
 self.pdfViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                 target:self 
                                                 action:@selector(shutDown)];
 [self presentViewController:navController 
                    animated:YES 
                  completion:nil];
```

Your `shutDown` method will be sent to the presenting ViewController, not to your presented pdfViewController... so that's where you need to implement it.